# Open a blob file in a new tab of browser in Aura component

Tags: javascript, aura, blob

I was facing some problems finding a way to open a blob from an Aura (Lightning component) in a new tab of the browser, the window.close() function doesn't work because open with base URL of the lightning context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to open a new tab with the lightning navigation event like below

```
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push('SomeBinaryStringComehere');
var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: "application/pdf" }));
// var tab = window.open(fileURL); //this doesn't works well

var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
    "url": fileURL 
});
urlEvent.fire();
```